# How to mock a method which is creating new objects using mockito?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mockito

as seen below, the method updatedetails() of the class is the method to be tested.
it is creating objects "storage()" and i am not able to mock that.

```
class temp {
    fun updateDetails() {
        //do some work
        storage().set(storedata)
    }
}
```

even if i try to mock storage() using mockito, it says storage()'s property context have not been initialized.

Comment: Where you've defined your mocking code?

Comment: how is storage() method?